# Spring boot+spring security - how can I block CORS requests on application layer?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, cors

I have a spring boot application with spring security. When any client from a different host calls the API method from my application, he sees exception:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/test' from origin 'http://localhost:8088' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.
```

**But** my controller still accepts requests. I want to disable it. I want that spring security to decline these requests.

I tried this:

```
  @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .cors().and()
```

and this:

```
    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());
        return source;
    }
```

I think I don't understand the full picture, and I want to understand: how can I block CORS requests on the application layer? because by default - the application processes requests and just browser blocks response.

Answer (score 1):

A literal answer would be to check the request for an `Origin` header and reject it if one is present, but that won't solve your real problem.

An attacker can still trick a user into making a cross-origin request, they just can't use Ajax for it. They can still (for example) submit a form to a hidden iframe and launch the same kind of malicious requests.

The Same Origin Policy is only good for preventing an attacker from reading data through a third party. It can't stop them making requests. (And CORS just allows the Same Origin Policy to be selectively disabled).

If you want to defend against the payloads in the requests then you need to implement proper defences against [CSRF attacks](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/csrf).

Typically this will be matching a token that appears in the body of the previous page with matching data in a session. The Same Origin Policy prevents the attacker from reading the token from the previous page.

Since you are using Spring, use its [built-in CSRF defences](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.x/reference/html/csrf.html).